# Django serialize function returns error JSONEncoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I'm trying to serilize my `salesnetwork.agency` model into a geojson file, and according to [Django docs](https://%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/) I'm using the following code:

(I'm using Django 4.1.2)

```
markers = Agency.objects.all()
geojson_file = serialize("geojson",
                          markers,
                          geometry_field="location",
                          fields=("province",)
               )
```

But this code results in the following error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vahid Moradi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Vahid Moradi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
...
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\navidmotor\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    path("", include("core.urls")),
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Vahid Moradi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\core\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import (
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\core\views.py", line 13, in <module>
    class HomePageView(ListView):
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\core\views.py", line 31, in HomePageView
    context = {"markers": json.loads(serialize("geojson",
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 134, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\djgeojson\serializers.py", line 471, in serialize
    self.end_serialization()
  File "D:\Projects\Navid Motor\Website\Django\NavidMotor.com\.venv\lib\site-packages\djgeojson\serializers.py", line 253, in end_serialization
    json.dump(self.feature_collection, self.stream, cls=cls, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\Vahid Moradi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 173, in dump
    iterable = cls(skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
TypeError: JSONEncoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'
```

Which is about the `field` field in the `serialize` function. So where is my problem? I wrote as the docs instructed.

I've also added the following to my settings:

```
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {"geojson": "djgeojson.serializers"}
```

Comment: You say you are following Django's documentation but from the traceback it looks like it ends up using a serializer from another package (probably https://django-geojson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) Have you by any chance set the [SERIALIZATION_MODULES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#serialization-modules) setting?

Comment: Indeed I have. `SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {"geojson": "djgeojson.serializers"}` is in my settings, I think somewhere in the middle of my last problem I've added this. Should I delete it? Is it OK?
EDIT: I commented out that line and it solved my problem. Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: The serializer from that package is being used as I said, if you remove that you won't get this error I guess, Maybe if you want to keep it you can give it a different format name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error traceback it can be noticed that some code in `djgeojson\serializers.py` is called instead of `django/contrib/gis/...` also as  you've confirmed you've set the following in your setting:

```py
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {"geojson": "djgeojson.serializers"}
```

This means when you want Django to use a formatter with the name being "geojson" it's going to use it from `djgeojson.serializers`, you can either remove that setting if you don't use the serializer from that package or if you want to continue using it you could simply update the name you use for it:

```py
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {"djgeojson": "djgeojson.serializers"}
```

Comment: Since I had no use for the `SERIALIZATION_MODULES = {"geojson": "djgeojson.serializers"}` line, I simply commented it out.